# How to dynamically create buttons and add events to them?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, events, button

I have array of buttons, and array of labels:
  
`Label[] labels = new Label[10];
Button[] but = new Button[10];`

While clicking the other button I want to dynamically create new button and new label from the array, i also want the but[i] to change the tex of labels[i]:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labels[i] = new Label();
        labels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 15+a);
        labels[i].Parent = panel1;
        labels[i].Text = "Sample text";
        labels[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 51);
        labels[i].BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        a = labels[i].Height + labels[i].Top;

        but[i] = new Button();
        but[i].Text = "-";
        but[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, labels[i].Height + labels[i].Top);
        but[i].Parent = panel1;
        but[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 10);
        but[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(but_Click);
        i++;
    }
    private void but[i]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labels[i].Text = "Changed Text";
    }
```

But apparently I can't put an array in an event handler, how should I do it then?

Comment: Wow really amazing "but[i]_Click" wouldn't even thought of something like that. Yet, that is not possible at least in c#. To the topic, what are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Is it only about `how to fire events dynamicly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the array index to the button as Tag property, and then pull it back out in but_Click.

So, add

```
but[i].Tag = i;
```

to the button creation. And then change the event handler:

```
private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int buttonIndex = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
    labels[buttonIndex].Text = "Changed Text";
}
```

Or put the event handler inline:

```
but[i].Click += (s,e) => { label[i].Text = "Changed Text"; }
```

Or another option using the Tag property, add:

```
but[i].Tag = label[i];

...

private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)((Button)sender).Tag;
    label.Text = "Changed Text";
}
```

Advantage of this approach is you're not relying on keeping arrays in synch after the initial creation of the controls.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to make your method *return* a handler instead of *being* a handler:

```
private EventHandler but_Click(int i)
{
    return (s, e) => labels[i].Text = "Changed Text";
}
```

And use it like:

```
but[i].Click += but_Click(i);
```

Or do it inline:

```
but[i].Click += (s, ea) => labels[i].Text = "Changed Text";
```

What's happening in either of these is some compiler magic to capture the `i` variable. It's equivalent to this (which is also a valid, if verbose, way to do it):

```
class MyWrapper {
    private int i;
    public MyWrapper(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public void TheHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // TODO: capture the object that owns `labels` also, or this won't work.
        labels[i].Text = "Changed Text";
    }
}

//call with
but[i].Click += new EventHandler(new MyWrapper(i).TheHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is self-explaining:

```
public void SomeMehthod()
{
    Button btn1 = new Button();
    Button btn2 = new Button();
    Button btn3 = new Button();

    // Your button-array
    Button[] btns = new Button[]
    {
        btn1,
        btn2,
        btn3
    };

    foreach(Button btn in btns)
    {
        // For each button setup the same method to fire on click
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClicked);
    }
}

private void ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This will fire on any button from the array
    // You can switch on the name, or location or anything else
    switch((sender as Button).Name)
    {
        case "btn1":
            // Do something
            break;
        case "btn2":
            // Do something
            break;
        case "btn3":
            // Do something
            break;
    }
}
```

**Or if your array is accessible globaly:**

```
Button[] btns = new Button[5];
Label[] lbls = new Label[5];

private void ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clicked = sender as Button;
    int indexOfButton = btns.ToList().IndexOf(clicked);

    // ..IndexOf() returns -1 if nothign is found
    if(indexOfButton > 0)
    {
        lbls[indexOfButton].DoWhatYouWant...
    }
}
```